# How To Select one of the same multiple elements in cheerio nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I'm trying to scrape links from a page, but the problem I'm facing right now is that i want to **scrape** href from anchor tag, but it has multiple tags with no class inside them.

It looks something like this

```
<div class="class1">
<a href="sample.com">Some random text</a>
<a href="example.com">Some random text</a>
</div>
```

Now I want to get example.com but when i try `find(".class1").find("a").attr("href");` it returns me sample.com.

I want to do something like this to get example.com instead of sample.com
`find(".class1").find("a")[1].attr("href");`
returns example.com

please someone help me with this. I'm a newbie to cheerio and cheerio's documentation is so much confusing to me.

Comment: "I want to do something like this" well it looks neat, just do it, what's the result? Also, what about `find(.class1).find("a:last-child")` ?

Comment: @jeremy-thille I'm getting undefined with `find(".class1").find("a")[1].attr("href");` ...Yess! i got example.com when i used `.find("a:last-child")` but what if there are more than just 2? like 11 anchor tags, so how can i get 4th one??

Comment: With `.find("a:nth-child(4)")` (that's a standard CSS selector). I've posted my comment as an answer, as it seems to have solved your problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the n-th `<a>` element using :

```
find(".class1").find("a:nth-child(4)").attr("href");
```